# How to map username and password to another mobile app for autofilling

Tags: android, autofill

I am having a homework problem where in I have to create an app that auto fills username(which can be a email also) and password to another mobile app or website.I am able auto fill the username to another app such as Instagram but not able to associate the respective usernames with their password.I am newbie in android and unable to figure out what to do at this moment any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance

1. Gone through the Google documentation of auto fill-framework.In the google documentation
   https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill-services

   I ran into few errors such as unable to resolve parse Structure(structure) and fetch User Data(parsed Structure).I was unable to figure out what to do in this situation so I did some google searching and searched for a few blogs.
2. Referred few stack over flow links.
3. The blog with which I was able to auto fill username's 
   https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-android-os-autofill-framework--cms-28811

My manifest file
**Manifest . XML**

```
<?XML version="1.0" encoding="u t f-8"?>
<manifest x m l n s :android="httpd://s c h e mas.android.com/a p k/res/android"
    package="com . example .simple fill">

    <application
        android : allow Backup="true"
        android:icon="@m i p map/i c_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android : round Icon="@m i p map/i c_launcher_round"
        android: supports R t l="true"
        android:theme="@style/App Theme">
        <activity android:name=".Main Activity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".Email Address Filler"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_AUTO FILL_SERVICE">
            <meta-data android:name="android.auto fill"
                android:resource="@XML/email_address_filler"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android .service .auto fill .Auto fill Service"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activity_main .XML**

```
<?XML version="1.0" encoding="u t f-8"?>
<Linear Layout
    x m l n s :android="ht t p://schema s. android.com/a p k/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16 DP">

    <com .google .android .material .text field .Text Input Layout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Edit Text
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/user"
            android:hint="Username"
            android: input Type="text Email Address"/>
    </com .google .android .material .text field .Text Input Layout>

    <com.google.android.material.text field. Text Input Layout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Edit Text
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/pass"
            android:hint="Password"
            android : input Type="text Email Address"/>
    </com .google .android .material .text field .Text Input Layout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/save_button"
        style="@style/Widget.App C o m p a t .Button.Colored"
        android:text="Save"
        android :on Click="save User Details"/>

</Linear Layout>
```

**Main Activity.java**

```
package com .example .simple fill;

import android x .app comp a t .app .App Comp a t Activity;

import android .content .Shared Preferences;
import android. OS. Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android .widget .Edit Text;

public class Main Activity extends App Comp at Activity {

    @Override
    protected void on Create(Bundle saved Instance State) {
        super.on Create(saved Instance State);
        set Content View(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void save Email Addresses(View view) {
        Shared Preferences.Editor editor = get Shared Preferences("EMAIL_STORAGE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        String primary Email Address = ((Edit Text)find View By Id(R.id.primary)).get Text().to String();
        String secondary Email Address = ((Edit Text)find View By Id(R.id.secondary)).get Text().to String();
        editor.put String("PRIMARY_EMAIL", primary Email Address);
        editor.put String("SECONDARY_EMAIL", secondary Email Address);
        editor.commit();

    }
}
```

**email_suggestion.XML**

```
<?XML version="1.0" encoding="u t f-8"?>
<Text View x m l n s :android="ht t p://schema s. android. com/a p k/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/email_suggestion_item"
    android : text Size="18 s p"
    android : text Style="bold"
    android:padding="5 d p">
</Text View>
```

**email_address_filler XML**

```
<?XML version="1.0" encoding="u t f-8"?>
<auto fill-service x m l n s: android="ht t p://schema s. android.com/a p k/res/android"
    android : settings Activity="com .example .simple fill .Main Activity">

</auto fill-service>
```

**Email Address Filler.java**

```
package com .example .simple fill;

import android.app.assist.Assist Structure;
import android.content.Shared Preferences;
import android .OS. Cancellation Signal;
import android. service .auto fill .Auto fill Service;
import android.service.auto fill. Data set;
import android.service.auto fill.Fill Callback;
import android.service.auto fill.Fill Context;
import android.service.auto fill.Fill Request;
import android.service.auto fill.Fill Response;
import android.service.auto fill.Save Callback;
import android.service.auto fill.Save Info;
import android.service.auto fill. Save Request;
import android.view.auto fill.Auto fill Id;
import android.view.auto fill.Auto fill Value;
import android.widget.Remote Views;

import java.util.Array List;
import java.util.List;

public class Email Address Filler extends Auto fill Service {
    @Override
    public void on Fill Request(Fill Request fill Request, Cancellation Signal cancellation Signal, Fill Callback fill Callback) {

        // Create an empty list
        List<Fill Context> contexts = fill Request.get Fill Contexts();
        List<Assist Structure.View Node> email Fields = new Array List<>();
        List<Assist Structure.View Node> p w d Fields = new Array List<>();
        Assist Structure structure = contexts.get(contexts.size() - 1).get Structure();

// Populate the list
        identify Email Fields(structure
                .get Window Node At(0)
                .get Root View Node(), email Fields);
        identify P w d Fields(structure
                .get Window Node At(0)
                .get Root View Node(), p w d Fields);
        if(email Fields.size() == 0)
            return;
        if(p w d Fields.size() == 0)
            return;
        Remote Views r v Primary Email =
                new Remote Views(get Package Name(),
                        R.layout.email_suggestion);

        Remote Views r v Secondary Email =
                new Remote Views(get Package Name(),
                        R.layout.email_suggestion);

// Load the email addresses from preferences
        Shared Preferences shared Preferences =
                get Shared Preferences("EMAIL_STORAGE", MODE_PRIVATE);

        String primary Email =
                shared Preferences.get String("PRIMARY_EMAIL", "");
        String secondary Email =
                shared Preferences.get String("SECONDARY_EMAIL", "");

// Update remote Text Views
        r v Primary Email.set Text View Text(R.id.email_suggestion_item,
                primary Email);
        r v Secondary Email.set Text View Text(R.id.email_suggestion_item,
                secondary Email);

        Assist Structure .View Node email Field = email Fields.get(0);
        Assist Structure. View Node p w d Field = p w d Fields.get(0);
        Data set primary Email Data Set =
                new Data set.Builder(r v Primary Email)
                        .set Value(
                                email Field.get Auto fill Id(),
                                Auto fill Value.for Text(primary Email)
                        ).build();

        Data set secondary Email Data Set =
                new Data set.Builder(r v Secondary Email)
                        .set Value(
                                p w d Field .get Auto fill Id(),
                                Auto fill Value .for Text(secondary Email)
                        ).build();

        Fill Response response = new Fill Response.Builder()
                .add Data set(primary Email Data Set)
                .add Data set(secondary Email Data Set)
                .build();


        fill Callback. on Success(response);
    }

    @Override
    public void on Save Request(Save Request save Request, Save Callback save Callback) {

    }
    void identify Email Fields(Assist Structure .View Node node, List<Assist Structure.View Node> email Fields) {

        if(node .get Class Name().contains("Edit Text")) {
            String view Id = node.get Id Entry();
            if(view Id!=null && (view Id.contains("email")
                    || view Id.contains("username"))) {
                email Fields.add(node);
                return;
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i<node.get Child Count();i++) {
            identify Email Fields(node .get Child At(i), email Fields);
        }

    }
    void identify P w d Fields(Assist Structure .View Node node, List<Assist Structure.View Node> p w d Fields) {

        if(node .get Class Name().contains("Edit Text")) {
            String view Id = node.get Id Entry();
            if(view Id!=null && (view Id.contains("password"))) {
                p w d Fields.add(node);
                return;
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i<node.get Child Count();i++) {
            identify P w d Fields(node.get Child At(i), p w d Fields);
        }

    }
}
```

If I am able to auto fill from my user Interface by typing the username and password and auto filling it to any mobile app(main requirement).It is more than enough.For websites then it would be great.

Comment: I would like to if it is possible to connect a database with my Autofill Service.Please Help.If so how?